# Change width of Kendo UI Grid Hierarchy?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a 13 column grid with 3 column hierarchy.

The issue is hierarchy grid is taking 13 column space evenly to display 3 columns .

Is there a way to set width of hierarchy grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the answer you are looking for.

```
function resizeDetailGrid(gridElement) {
    // resize detail column widths to match master column headings
    gridElement.find('.k-detail-cell tbody tr td').each(function (index) {
        var headerCell, detailCell, headerCellSelector, detailCellSelector;
        headerCellSelector = kendo.format('.k-master-row td:nth-child({0})', index + 2);
        detailCellSelector = kendo.format('.k-detail-cell tbody tr td:nth-child({0})', index + 1);
        headerCell = gridElement.find(headerCellSelector).first();
        detailCell = gridElement.find(detailCellSelector);
        detailCell.width(headerCell.width());
    });
}
```

And initialise the grid

```
    gridDetailInit: function () {
        resizeDetailGrid($('#grid'));
    }
```

You could also add a horizontal scroll bar to the grid if you have so many columns.

Hope this info helps.

Comment: [Link only answers are very frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/171858).

Answer (score 2):

In order to set smaller width for the hierarchy Grid you can explicitly set the width of the hierarchy Grid component. This can be done via the HtmlAttributes property.

```
.HtmlAttributes(new {style="width: 500px;" })
```

Comment: This works very well for setting the width of the child grid.